# Criar array/lista com índices

Tags: python, lista

Bom dia pessoal, comecei a aprender Python há alguns dias e, fazendo alguns testes com listas por aqui fiquei com algumas dúvidas.

1 - No PHP eu consigo criar um array definindo os índices dos seus valores:

```
<?php
$array = array( 1 => 'Jan', 2 => 'Fev', ..., 12 => 'Dez' );
?>
```

Porém não encontrei uma forma de fazer o mesmo no Python, é possível? Nas pesquisas que fiz acabei achando informações sobre a função index(), que não é bem o que procuro.

2 - Esses dias, olhando algum código por aqui, encontrei a seguinte linha:

```
your_list = [1,2,3]
a = [i for i in your_list]
a = [x+i for i in your_list for x in a]

print( a )
```

Eu entendi o que acontece, basicamente ele retorna uma lista com as somas possíveis entre os valores em your_list: [1+1, 1+2, 1+3, 2+1, 2+2, 2+3, 3+1, 3+2, 3+3]. O que me deixou curioso aqui foi: como reescrever a terceira linha pra separar os dois for.

Desde já obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Python não oferece o tipo `array` como tipo primitivo. Você pode
   trabalhar com `listas`, por exemplo, que possuem índices começando
   em 0.    Outra opção, é você usar módulos: há o módulo `array` do
   python `import array` e bibliotecas como o
   [NumPy](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html).
   Para criar "índices"  distintos python possui o tipo `dicionário`,
   onde  "índices" (*keys*) são associados a valores.

   ```
   dictionary = {'1':Jan, '2': Fev, ... , '12': Dez}
   ```
2. A segunda pergunta não ficou muito clara, mas repare que na segunda linha `a` é uma copia de `your_list`.
   O código da terceira linha é equivalente ao seguinte:

   ```
   list = []
   for i in your_list:
      for x in a:
         list.append(x+i)
   ```

Comment: Obrigado por tirar minhas dúvidas, vou dar uma olhada no NumPy.

Comment: Lembrando que índices (_keys_) no Python, podem ser vários tipos de dados imutáveis, como strings, números (float, long ou int, tanto taz) e tuplas.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Para definir os índices seria preciso um dicionário em vez de uma lista:

```
dict1 = {1: "Jan", 2: "Fev", ..., 12: "Dez"}
```

**2.** O que acontece no código é uma list comprehension, separado ficaria assim:

```
your_list = [1,2,3]
a = [i for i in your_list]
b = []
for i in your_list:
    for x in a:
        b.append(x + i)
a = b

print( a )
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, vou pesquisar mais sobre List Comprehension